# Script not working for changing number of items to show in content search web part for some users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, content-search-web-part

I have this script to change the number of items to show in CSWP

```
function loadScript(selectObject) {

  var newItems = parseInt(selectObject.value);
  var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
  var currentCtx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var pageFile = currentCtx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
  var webPartManager = pageFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
  var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();

  currentCtx.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');
  currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
          if (webPartDefs.get_count()) {
              for (var i = 0; i < webPartDefs.get_count(); i++) {
                  var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                  var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
                  var properties = webPart.get_properties();
                  if (properties.get_fieldValues().Title.indexOf("Content Search") > -1) {
                      properties.set_item("ResultsPerPage", newItems);
                      webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
                      currentCtx.load(webPartDef);
                      currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(
                          function () {
                              console.log("Web Part properties saved.");
                              location.replace("My Clients.aspx");
                          },
                          function (err) {
                              console.log(err);
                          });
                  }
              }
          }
          else {
              console.log("No Web Parts Found.");
          }
      },
      function (sender, args) {
          console.log(args.get_message());
      });
}
```

But is only working for some users, I realized that the users with 'Read' (or less) permissions are the users facing this issue. What else should be done in order to get this working correctly for these users?

I performed debug on Dev Tools, no errors, actually I can see console.log and the location.replace is performed.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, this part here is causing the issue:

```
if (properties.get_fieldValues().Title.indexOf("Content Search") > -1) {
                  properties.set_item("ResultsPerPage", newItems);
                  webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
                  currentCtx.load(webPartDef);
                  currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(
```

Specifically, the line webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();. Users with read access only will not be able to modify any content on a given page, including webpart settings.

Comment: That's correct, is there any workaround to get this working even from that users?

Comment: So if I understand, this whole thing is to change the number of of items that show in a content search query webpart. Is it related to some max limit problem? If that is the case, have you considered using a REST call to execute a search? There you would not be limited by any item count, and there you would not have any access issues.

Comment: I have a functionality in my web parts page in a dropdown list for users to choose the number of items they want to see, that's why I created this script. Do you have an example on doing by REST call? Thanks in advance.